# Tensor flow: nn.tanh is not converging (C++ version works very well)

Tags: tensorflow

I ported a very simple working C++ neural network to Tensorflow, however, tensor flow version does not converge in training. It's a combinator of many Netflix predictors and operates on Netflix prize prediction data set.

### Here is the tensorflow program:

```
from Blender import Blender, rating2internal, internal2rating
import math
import tensorflow as tf

GLOBAL_MEAN = 3.6033
NUNITS = 12


bl=Blender('/Users/dsu/src/blend/nncontrol.txt')
print('y shape:',bl.proberesults.shape )

STDDEV = tf.sqrt(1.0 /bl.nPredictors)
STDDEV2 = tf.sqrt(1.0 /NUNITS)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, bl.nPredictors])
print('nPredictors=%d' % bl.nPredictors)
print('nRatings=%d' % bl.nRatings)
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None, 1])

W1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([bl.nPredictors, NUNITS], stddev=STDDEV))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([NUNITS]))    
W2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([NUNITS,1], stddev=STDDEV))
#b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1])) #
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.fill([1], math.atanh(rating2internal(GLOBAL_MEAN))))

middle = tf.nn.tanh(tf.matmul(x, W1)+ b1)
y = tf.nn.tanh(tf.matmul(middle, W2) + b2)

loss = tf.nn.l2_loss (y - y_)
train_error = tf.sqrt( loss * 8 / bl.nRatings)
print_train_error = tf.Print(train_error, [train_error], message = 'trainning error =')

#sess = tf.Session()
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(4e-4).minimize(loss)
for i in range(20):
  xs = bl.proberatings
  ys = bl.proberesults
  sess.run([train_step, print_train_error], feed_dict={x: xs, y_: ys})
```

---

Training runs, with training errors GROWING over time (first iteration has about similar training error to C++ version):

```
Successfully loaded proberesults
Successfully loaded proberatings
('y shape:', (1408395, 1))
nPredictors=148
nRatings=1408395
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] trainning error =[1.1299249]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] trainning error =[1.7401197]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] trainning error =[2.9758246]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] trainning error =[1.565937]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] trainning error =[1.5658225]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] trainning error =[1.5657765]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] trainning error =[1.5657219]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] trainning error =[1.5657307]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] trainning error =[1.5656669]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] trainning error =[1.5657002]
```

Anything wrong? The C++ version will train 1000 iterations and training errors consistently go down from 1.0x level to 0.87. Tried a few changes, still not converging.

Comment: Diverging training is a common behavior for neural networks, there's probably an implementation difference between your TensorFlow and your C++ versions. Things to try: reduce learning rate, reduce STDDEV for initialization, replace GradientDescentOptimizer with AdamOptimizer

Comment: Thanks. C++ version is a fairly simple single-thread one and is not so sensitive to parameters initialization and achieves much better result after even first iteration. The difference likely lies in gradient update. AdamOptimizer does converge, however, first iteration still ends up much higher than C++ and final result is worse than C++ one, most importantly, its result is not useable.